# Getting error in code DataSnapshot snap in flutter using firbase database

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am working on a flutter application. I am trying to create a registeration process. I had written the following code for login.

```
void loginRest(BuildContext context) async {
final User = (await firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: emailTextController.text,
    password: passwordTextController.text)
    .catchError((errMsg) {
  if (errMsg.code == "user-not-found") {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(
          content: Text(
            "Login Details are Incorrect",
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.red, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18.0),
          )
        )
    );
  } else if (errMsg.code == "wrong-password") {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(
          content: Text(
            "Password is Wrong",
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.red, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18.0),
          )
        )
    );
  } else if (errMsg.code == "invalid-email") {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(
          content: Text(
            "Email Format is not Valid",
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.red, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18.0),
          )
        )
    );
  } else {
    displayToastMessage("Error: $errMsg", context);
  }
})).user;
if (User != null) // user created
    {
  //Save user information into Database
  showDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return ProgressBar(
          message: "Authenticating Please Wait...",
        );
      });

  user_reference.child(User.uid).once().then((DataSnapshot snap) {
        if (snap.value != null) {
          showDialog(
              context: context,
              barrierDismissible: false,
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return ProgressBar(
                  message: "Authenticating Please Wait...",
                );
              });
          Navigator.push(
              context,
              PageRouteBuilder(
                  transitionDuration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                  transitionsBuilder:
                      (context, animation, animationTime, child) {
                    animation = CurvedAnimation(
                        parent: animation,
                        curve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn);
                    return ScaleTransition(
                      scale: animation,
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: child,
                    );
                  },
                  pageBuilder: (context, animation, animationTime) {
                    return HomeScreen();
                  }));
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
              content: Text(
                "You have been login Sucessfully",
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 18.0),
              )));
        } else {
          _firebaseAuth.signOut();
          displayToastMessage(
              "User doesnt exist , please create new account", context);
        }
      };
  );
} else {
  displayToastMessage("Error Occured", context);
}
}
```

I am getting error in following part of code: `user_reference.child(User.uid).once().then((DataSnapshot snap) {...}`

I also add the dependencies of firebase database and import the library: `import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';`

This is the image of the error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZjBz.jpg
[image: Error]

I don't know what wrong I am doing because I am doing it for the first time. If someone caught the error please explain me a little bit with the correct answer. Thankyou.

Comment: "I am getting error" Please edit your question to show the exact error message and complete stack trace that you get.

Comment: I am not getting error while compiling, the error occurs in code. Maybe there will be a syntax error which I am not aware of. I had add the error image in the question above.

Comment: What's userReference?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I had upload the text form of code in the question above. The image is just to see that I am getting some type of error in the code, might be syntax.

Comment: An error message is also textual content, so should also be posted as text. That gives you the added advantage of being able to search for the error message, as others may have had the same problem before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you mean to be writing

```
userReference.doc(User.uid).get().then((DocumentSnapshot snap) {...?
```

Otherwise show what userReference is, since it's unclear what you're actually doing there otherwise.

Comment: The userReference is 'DatabaseReference userReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("User");' Is your is correct after seeing the userReference?

Comment: You must be using a plugin with which I am unfamiliar.  Firebase api's for flutter don't include DatabaseReference, and that language isn't part of Firebase usage.  My example above is standard.  It could be that you are using a very old version, I see you're not using null safety.  I suggest you follow more up to date tutorials and reference in that case.